# PCA plot reduction dimensionality

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I m try to cluster using PCA technique.

In my case i have review made by user of n movies.
I create a table user x movie in this way :

```
User    Movie
        0 1 2 3 4 
      0 2 0 5 0 0
      1 0 1 1 0 0
      2 0 5 5 5 0
```

where 0 if user not review a movie and 1-5 if he review from 1 to 5 stars.
and the shape is (6040, 3706)

I Normalize the data and after
I use this code for PCA (from sklearn)

```
pca = PCA(0.7)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(X_std)

a = pca_result[:,0]
b = pca_result[:,1]
```

i use 0.7 for cluster because my cumulative explained variance
[image]

so for me is very rappresentative value 0.7 
and my new shape is (6040, 650)

After i see the dimension will be plot in this way (but I don't think is very significant)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,16))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


ax.scatter(a,b, alpha = 1)
plt.title('Method: PCA')
plt.show()
```

But in this way i put A on X axis and B on Y axis ,so I m think using just two dimensions (because I seen all example with two dimensions).

[image]

**So my question is i dont plot all of dimensions? (In my case 650 remain dimensions?)** 
**What am I doing wrong?**

Maybe my question can be stupid, but i m try to understand this topic.

Comment: You plotted `a` value against `b` value for your 650 "surviving" factors.  I expect that your plot above has 650 data points.  Or perhaps this is the variable plot for all 3706 points, and the ones close to 0 were the least important.  I can't tell, because you haven't included enough of your code to follow the algorithm.

Comment: for me a and b are 2 vector of 6040 @Prune i don't have more code, before this code i just use a normalization from sklearn and create a matrix user for movie...nothing to much

Answer (score 2):

Don't use 0 to encode missing values (in particular, not with PCA).

This is the maximum difference to a 5, so in essence you are right now assuming that users *hate* all movies they did not rate.

I don't know if there is any variant of PCA that works with missing data. Usually it seems to assume you have all the the values. So you likely need to choose other algorithms.